# (org.apache.httpd[7396]): Exited with code: 1

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

I have ran into a problem and I dont get a clue of whats happening. I am trying to access my localhost but for some reason apache is crashing endlesly.

```
    Sep  9 19:06:40 mothership com.apple.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd[7396]): Exited with code: 1
    Sep  9 19:06:40 mothership com.apple.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

here is my system.log https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3230707/system.log

Comment: Are any useful messages in apaches error.log?

Comment: the only thing I know is thats related to apache. I have attached the system log file.

Comment: Look in apache's error log: /var/log/apache2/error_log; that'll have much more relevant info than the system log.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem, if i run

> sudo apachectl -t

i get :

> httpd: Syntax error on line 117 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n  Reason: image not found

it says it can not find "/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib" so i simlinked with :

> cd /usr/lib
>
> sudo ln -s libpq.dylib libpq.5.dylib

Comment: Could you clarify how this is (a) the same problem as the original poster's extremely vague question, and (b) a helpful answer?

Comment: i had the same error in system.log but you are right maybe it is not exactly the same cause. At least the original poster can see that if he run "apachectl -t" he can have more details on his problem

Comment: It is an helpful answer because it helps to find out what (and where) the error is occurring. In my case, the apache error_log wasn't getting logged - it was going to the system log, similar to the question from OP